# MS Access Query - Display Exclusive Records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have built a Query that lists the Top 100 SKUs sold with in the company this year. We sell over 650 Items, with multiple variations on size of this item which ranges out to around 15,000 total SKU's I am trying to write a query that will show orders made exclusively of the top 100 SKU's but all I am able to get are orders that contain the a SKU in the Top 100.

Here is a look at my SQL statement

```
SELECT 
  Year([DATE_FLD]) AS Expr1, 
  tbl_SalesOrderDetail.ITEM_CODE, 
  tbl_SalesOrderDetail.CUST_CODE, 
  tbl_SalesOrderDetail.DOC_NO
FROM (tbl_SalesOrderDetail 
LEFT JOIN qry_NotTop100 
  ON tbl_SalesOrderDetail.ITEM_CODE = qry_NotTop100.Code) 
INNER JOIN qry_Top100 
  ON tbl_SalesOrderDetail.ITEM_CODE = qry_Top100.Code
WHERE (((Year([DATE_FLD]))=Year(Date())) AND ((qry_NotTop100.Code) Is Null))
ORDER BY tbl_SalesOrderDetail.DOC_NO;
```

Any Ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: can you show us what is in qry_Top100 and qry_NotTop100. What do they return?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an anti-join. There are multiple ways to do that, `NOT IN` is one of those ways. `NOT IN` isn't necessarily very efficient, but you get the idea on where to improve upon things.

- Remove the `LEFT JOIN` to `qry_NotTop100`.
- Remove the `WHERE` clause on `qry_NotTop100`
- Add to the `WHERE` clause `AND tbl_SalesOrderDetail.ITEM_CODE NOT IN ( SELECT qry_NotTop100.Code FROM qry_NotTop100 )`